# Using chromaprint.js in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, coffeescript

I'm currently in the process of building a music streaming website and want to use the [chromaprint.js](https://github.com/bjjb/chromaprint.js) library for deduplication purposes.

I use browserify and gulp in the pipeline, and although the library states it can be used in the browser, all attempts to `require()` the library have been unsuccessful, yielding the "Cannot find module" error:

```
$ gulp
[11:19:26] Using gulpfile ~/xxx/gulpfile.js
[11:19:26] Starting 'scripts'...
[11:19:26] Starting 'styles'...
[11:19:26] Starting 'html'...
[11:19:26] Finished 'html' after 73 ms
[11:19:27] Finished 'styles' after 833 ms
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'chromaprint.js' from '/home/user/xxx'
    at /home/user/xxx/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/home/user/xxx/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/home/user/xxx/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/home/user/xxx/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/home/user/xxx/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /home/user/xxx/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

Here is my code for importing:

```
var chromaprint = require("chromaprint.js");
```

I've attempted requiring coffeescript just in case as this lib is written in coffeescript, but it doesn't seem to affect the loading issue.

```
require("coffeescript");
```

The library hasn't seen a commit for a few months and the author seems unresponsive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` file should read something like:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...,
   "chromaprint.js": "*"
}
```

And you'll need to include the file via `npm i chromaprint.js` at the command-line.

Comment: Ah, sorry should've included that in the question. Yes, I currently have chromaprint.js in my package.json, at version `"^0.1.0"`. The package is installed and listed under `./node_modules/chromaprint.js/`. I just can't seem to require it.

Comment: @wires Could I see a little more code and the package.json file.